# Two consecutive Toast messages won't show when they are called exactly after each other on Android Oreo

Tags: android, kotlin, android-8.0-oreo, android-toast

The following code properly shows two consecutive messages on devices running `Android version lower than 27`, but on `Android version 27`, it just shows the message of the first `Toast`.

What has changed in `Android 27` that makes it behave differently?

Should two consecutive Toast messages have gap longer than specific time?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    Toast.makeText(this, "The onCreate method is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    Toast.makeText(this, "The onResume method is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mehrdad, I am facing the same problem with Android 9. Did you find a solution? Thanks

Comment: No Unfortunately. But consider that I am no longer engaged in Android Developing. Maybe some fixed has came for this problem since then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a small program that tracks State
I ran with API 26 and API 27 and this line of code is only called when you navigate back from another Activity

```
Toast.makeText(this, "The onResume method is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Enjoy

OK Here is how you write a small program that tracks STATE
This is the Activity that Gives you output set your logcat to debug note the TAG

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val TAG = "LifeCycle"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "${javaClass.simpleName} OnCreate")
    println("========================== OnCreate")
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onStart() {
    Log.d(TAG, "${javaClass.simpleName} OnStart")
    println("========================== OnStart")
    super.onStart()
}

override fun onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "${javaClass.simpleName} OnResume")
    println("========================== OnResume")
    super.onResume()
}

override fun onRestart() {
    Log.d(TAG, "${javaClass.simpleName} OnRestart")
    println("========================== OnRestart")
    super.onRestart()
}

override fun onPause() {
    Log.d(TAG, "${javaClass.simpleName} OnPause")
    println("========================== OnPause")
    super.onPause()
}

override fun onStop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "${javaClass.simpleName} OnStop")
    println("========================== OnStop")
    super.onStop()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "${javaClass.simpleName} OnDestroy")
    println("========================== OnDestroy")
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

}

Then as you Navigate from one Activity Class to another you will get output
Provided you use this heading in the Class

```
class WelcomeActivity : BaseActivity() {
```

Comment: I think you got the question wrong. The problem is that calling two `Toast` message (even in one state - for example calling two `Toast`s in `onCreate`) won't show the second `Toast` and only will show the first `Toast` message.
I have already used `Log` to track the application lifecycle states, and everything was OK.

Comment: @MehrdadSComputer Let me try to understand this. If you use API 27 both show but if you change to API 26 then only one shows?

Comment: If I run the code on an emulator which has Android API 27, it only shows the first Toast message, but if I run the same code on an emulator that has Android API 25, it shows both Toast messages after each other (in order).